# How to connect two different folders and give them two different passwords and usernames with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have these two folders "slacktest1" and "slacktest2" who is inside the "slacktest1" folder.The two folders are in the "htdocs" folder (I am using xampp)
and in that folder I have my ".htaccess" and ".password" folder.Now I want to have It so the "slacktest1" and "slacktest2" folders when accessed have two different passwords and usernames,but I don not know how to connect them with ".htaccess"

Heres my code so far for ".htaccess":

```
          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "Please enter username and password"
          AuthUserFile C:\xampp\htdocs\slacktest1\.password
          Require user user1
```

and the code for ".password":

```
           name123:123
```

I hope someone can answer my question,I am a beginner at all the apache stuff so thank you :D!